# Scala: immutability and path-dependent type compatibility

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

I have asked a few questions around this topic but this time I want to make it a more general discussion, since it seems to me that Scala is lacking some very important blocks.

Consider the following code (which is simplified from my real project),

```
trait World {
  type State <: StateIntf
  def evolve(s: State): State
  def initialState: State
}

class Algorithm(world: World) {
  def process(s: world.State) {
    val s1 = world.evolve(s)
    // ... do something with s and s1
  }
}
```

Everything seems so beautiful and mathematical, but

```
object SomeWorld extends World {...}
new Algorithm(SomeWorld).process(SomeWorld.initialState)  // incompatible type
```

Certainly you can do in the following way

```
trait World {
  type State <: StateIntf
  var s: State
  def evolve: Unit      // s = next state
  def initialize: Unit  // s = initial state
  def getState: StateIntf = s
}
```

But we are just back to the mutable world.

I am told that this is because Scala does not have flow analysis. If that is the problem, shouldn't Scala get that piece? I only need that compilor can be aware that values passed from `val` to `val` are the same so that their inner types must agree. This seems so natural to me, as:

1. `val` is the most foundamental concept that involves immutability in scala
2. Path dependent type compatability is needed to model things like `World` with complete immutability (which is highly desired from a mathematical perspective)
3. Flow analysis of passing `val`s solve the problem

Am I asking for too much? Or is there already a nice way of solving it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler sometimes needs a little bit of help to prove that what you are doing is legal when using path dependent types. I.e., as you said, the compiler is missing flow analysis, so we must tell it explicitly that we aren't just using any `World`, we are using exactly `SomeWorld` so that we can use `SomeWorld.initialState`.

In your case, if you change `Algorithm` like so:

```
class Algorithm[W <: World](world: W) {
  def process(s: world.State) {
    val s1 = world.evolve(s)
    // ... do something with s and s1
  }
}
```

Then the following compiles:

```
object SomeWorld extends World {...}
new Algorithm[SomeWorld.type](SomeWorld).process(SomeWorld.initialState)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that generics provides a simpler solution to this problem:

```
trait World[S <: StateInf] {
  def evolve(s: S): S
  def initialState: S
}

class Algorithm[S <: StateInf](world: World[S]) {
  def process(s: S) {
    val s1 = world.evolve(s)
    // ... do something with s and s1
  }
}
```

Comment: I think upper type bound like [S <: StateInf] should be added to type parameters.

Comment: @Odomontois Thanks. I forgot the bound.

Comment: After 2+ yrs... eventually realized why generics do not work for me (but in most cases I would say your solution is great). In my situation, I have two worlds with the same state type, and I want to apply World 1's function to a state generated in World 2, but the state must be passed through a converter before used. This behavior is best modeled by inner type, since generics will allow applying the function without conversion, which is dangerous as it compiles and runs but produces nonsense. I have to say I almost made this mistake several times and was warned every time during compile-time.