# Path-Dependent type inside class value in Scala

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

I would like to give a value of a type with an abstract type to a class and later use it's path dependent type. Look at the following example (using Scala 2.10.1):

```
trait Foo {
  type A
  def makeA: A
  def useA(a: A): Unit
}

object Test {

  class IntFoo extends Foo {
    type A = Int
    def makeA = 1
    def useA(a: Int) = println(a)
  }

  class FooWrap(val a: Foo) {
    def wrapUse(v: a.A) = a.useA(v)
  }

  val foo = new IntFoo

  /* Path dependent locally */
  val bar = foo  
  bar.useA(foo.makeA)   // works

  /* Path dependent through class value */
  val fooWrap = new FooWrap(foo)

  fooWrap.a.useA(foo.makeA)  // fails
  // error: type mismatch; found : Int required: Test.fooWrap.a.A

  fooWrap.wrapUse(foo.makeA) // fails
  // error: type mismatch; found : Int required: Test.fooWrap.a.A

}
```

First, I do not understand the fundamental difference between the local and the class-value case (note the public, immutable value) and why the type checking fails (because obviously `Test.fooWrap.a.A =:= foo.A`). Is this a limitation of the Scala compiler?

Second, how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

**UPDATE**

It seems that this can be achieved by using generics and inline type-constraints:

```
class FooWrap[T](val a: Foo { type A = T }) {
  def wrapUse(v: T) = a.useA(v)
}
```

However, in my case, `A` is actually a higher-kinded type, so the example becomes:

```
trait Foo {
  type A[T]
  def makeA[T]: A[T]
  def useA(a: A[_]): Unit
}

object Test {

  class OptFoo extends Foo {
    type A[T] = Option[T]
    def makeA[T] = None
    def useA(a: A[_]) = println(a.get)
  }

  class FooWrap(val a: Foo) {
    def wrapUse(v: a.A[_]) = a.useA(v)
  }

  val foo = new OptFoo

  /* Path dependent locally (snip) */

  /* Path dependent through class value */
  val fooWrap = new FooWrap(foo)

  fooWrap.a.useA(foo.makeA)  // fails
  // polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  // found : [T]None.type required: Test.fooWrap.a.A[_]

  fooWrap.wrapUse(foo.makeA) // fails
  // polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  // found : [T]None.type required: Test.fooWrap.a.A[_]

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544269/scala-immutability-and-path-dependent-type-compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original question, your problem is that the Scala compiler is unable to prove equality of the result type of `foo.makeA` with the argument type of `fooWrap.a.useA`. To do that it would need to be able to prove the identity of `foo` with `fooWrap.a` which we can intuitively see must be the case here, but which isn't straightforward for the compiler to track.

There are a couple of ways to work around this problem. First, you could use `fooWrap.a` uniformly in place of `foo`,

```
scala> fooWrap.a.useA(fooWrap.a.makeA)
1
```

Now it's simple for the compiler to recognize the prefix of A (`fooWrap.a`) as being the same in both occurrences.

Second, you could parametrize `FooWrap` in a way which captures the type of its `Foo` argument more precisely,

```
scala> class FooWrap[F <: Foo](val a: F) {
     |   def wrapUse(v: a.A) = a.useA(v)
     | }
defined class FooWrap

scala> val fooWrap = new FooWrap(foo)
fooWrap: FooWrap[IntFoo] = FooWrap@6d935671

scala> fooWrap.a.useA(foo.makeA)
1
```

Here the type argument of `FooWrap` is inferred as `IntFoo` rather than as bare `Foo`, hence `A` is known to be exactly `Int`, as it is in the result type of `foo.makeA`.

In your update you introduce an additional wrinkle: you change the signature of `useA` to,

```
def useA(a: A[_]): Unit
```

The `_` here is an existential which will frustrate all attempts to coax the compiler into proving useful type equalities. Instead you need something along the lines of,

```
trait Foo {
  type A[T]
  def makeA[T]: A[T]
  def useA[T](a: A[T]): Unit
}

class OptFoo extends Foo {
  type A[T] = Option[T]
  def makeA[T]: A[T] = None
  def useA[T](a: A[T]) = a map println
}

class FooWrap[F <: Foo](val a: F) {
  def wrapUse[T](v: a.A[T]) = a.useA(v)
}

val foo = new OptFoo
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> val fooWrap = new FooWrap(foo)
fooWrap: FooWrap[OptFoo] = FooWrap@fcc10a7

scala> fooWrap.a.useA(foo.makeA)

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

The higher kinded-type can be added to FooWrap as generic parameter, too:

```
class FooWrap[T[V]](val a: Foo { type A[V] = T[V] }) {
  def wrapUse(v: T[_]) = a.useA(v)
}
```

but (in this example) the inference fails:

```
val fooWrap = new FooWrap[Option](foo)
```

Otherwise:

```
- type mismatch; found : Test.foo.type (with underlying type Test.OptFoo) required: Foo{type A[V] = T[V]}
- inferred kinds of the type arguments (Option[V]) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type T) in class FooWrap. Option[V]'s type parameters do not match type T's expected 
 parameters: class Option has one type parameter, but type T has one
```

Any other, nicer solutions?