# Abstract reflection API in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-macros

Scala 2.10 comes with a great reflection API. There are two entry points to it, however: runtime universe and macro context universe.

When using runtime reflection, you should import `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`. When using reflection inside a macro implementation, you should import universe from the context.

Is it possible to write some code that works in both environments? How should one obtain the `universe`?

Consider this example:

```
class MyReflection(val u: scala.reflect.api.Universe) {
  import u._

  def foo[T: TypeTag] = implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe.members // returns MyReflection.u.MemberScope
}
val x = new MyReflection(scala.reflect.runtime.universe)
val members: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = x.foo[String] // BANG! Compiler error
```

This won't compile because of type mismatch. Same time, it is obvious that both `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope` and `MyReflection.u.MemberScope` in this example share the same API. Is there a way to abstract over different universes?

Or am I possibly doing something philosophically wrong with trying to export reflection artifacts (`MemberScope` in this example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just accept the universe as a parameter:

```
class MyReflection(val u: scala.reflect.api.Universe) {
  import u._

  def foo[T : TypeTag] = implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe.members
}


val x = new MyReflection(scala.reflect.runtime.universe)
```

Note that you'll have to refer to the universe via your instance of `MyReflection` to get the path-dependent types right.

```
val members: x.u.MemberScope = x.foo[String]
```

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180248/path-dependent-type-inside-class-value-in-scala) for more examples and options.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! While this hint is a solution, it has a noticeable downside for me. I've updated the question with the description of it.

Comment: Welcome to the downside of path-dependent types. You have no choice but to do everything you want to do under the scope of `MyReflection`, or refer to `MyReflection`'s implementation of `Universe`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) (see section "Writing bigger macros") will help me.